# Convert .htaccess to nginx with QUERY_STRING

Tags: nginx

Now I have a code like .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fb_action_ids=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?fb_comment_id=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Please help me convert it to nginx thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire query string is available as the `$args` variable. You can test the variable using an `if` statement.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)&?fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$) {
    return 301 $uri?$1$2;
}
if ($args ~ ^(.*)&?fb_action_ids=[^&]+&?(.*)$) {
    return 301 $uri?$1$2;
}
if ($args ~ ^(.*)&?fb_comment_id=[^&]+&?(.*)$) {
    return 301 $uri?$1$2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!